# Send parameter from controller to service in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following controller:

```
class DemandCtrl {
    constructor(ChartDataService) {
        this.ChartDataService = ChartDataService;
        this.dataa = {
            from: 'test1',
            to: 'test2'
        };
    }

    $onInit() {
        getData.call(null, this);       
    }

}


function getData(DemandCtrl) {
    debugger;
    DemandCtrl.ChartDataService.getData().then(result => {
        DemandCtrl.result = result.data;
        getChart(result.data);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
}


  ... other methods/functions...


DemandCtrl.$inject = ['ChartDataService'];

export const Demand = {
    bindings: {
        data: '<'
    },
    templateUrl: demandPageHtml,
    controller: DemandCtrl
};
```

I want to get the data from `dataa` to my service as parameters.

The service looks like this:

```
export default class ChartDataService {
    constructor($http, authService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.authService = authService;
    }
    getData() {
                return this.$http.get(`chartData?&fromDate=` + dataa.from + `&toDate=` + dataa.to)
.then(result => {
            return result;
        }).catch(() => {
            return Promise.reject('Failed to access chart data ');
        });
    }
}

ChartDataService.$inject = ['$http', 'authService'];
```

What I've tried is to give the `dataa` as a parameter to `getData()` but it says it is undefined. Probably I'm not sending them correctly from the controller but I don't know how should I do it.

Answer (score 0):

in the `ChartDataService` service, just return the `http` request instead of unwrapping the promise.

```
export default class ChartDataService {
    constructor($http, authService) {
        this.$http = $http;
        this.authService = authService;
    }
    getData(dataa) {
        return this.$http.get(`chartData?&fromDate=` + dataa.from + `&toDate=` + dataa.to) 
    }
}
```

Now pass the parameters like this.

```
DemandCtrl.ChartDataService.getData(this.dataa).then(result => {
        DemandCtrl.result = result.data;
        getChart(result.data);
    }).catch((e) => {
        console.log(e);
    });
```

Comment: I got error on `DemandCtrl.result = result.data;`:`standalone.js:16 TypeError: Cannot read property 'dataa' of null
    at getData (demand.js?a5a5:24)
    at DemandCtrl.$onInit (demand.js?a5a5:17)
    at standalone.js:16
    at forEach (standalone.js:16)
    at nodeLinkFn (standalone.js:16)
    at standalone.js:16
    at processQueue (standalone.js:16)
    at standalone.js:16
    at Scope.$digest (standalone.js:16)
    at Scope.$apply (standalone.js:16)
    at done (standalone.js:16)
    at completeRequest (standalone.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestLoaded (standalone.js:16)`